# FPS Unity Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a setup where I can freely look around when moving in my FPS Unity game. This code works and I should be able to look around but for some reason I cannot look up or down and I don't understand why. This should be the only code affecting the look around capability. Please help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [SerializeField] float mouseSensitivity;
    [SerializeField] Transform player, playerArms;
    
    float xAxisClamp = 0;
    
    void Update()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        RotateCamera();
    }
    
    void RotateCamera()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        
        float rotAmountX = mouseX * mouseSensitivity;
        float rotAmountY = mouseY * mouseSensitivity;
        
        xAxisClamp -= rotAmountY;
        
        Vector3 rotPlayerArms = playerArms.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        Vector3 rotPlayer = player.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        
        rotPlayerArms.x -= rotAmountY;
        rotPlayerArms.z = 0;
        rotPlayer.y += rotAmountX;
        
        if(xAxisClamp > 90)
        {
            xAxisClamp = 90;
            rotPlayerArms.x = 90;
        }
        else if (xAxisClamp < -90)
        {
            xAxisClamp = -90;
            rotPlayerArms.x = 270;
        }
            
        playerArms.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotPlayerArms);
        player.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (rotPlayer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the x-axis rotation you're applying for your arms to your camera too. You can either set your player camera to be the child of your PlayerArms transform, or change your code:

```
playerArms.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotPlayerArms);
player.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (rotPlayer);
```

To this:

```
playerArms.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotPlayerArms);
player.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (rotPlayer);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotPlayerArms);
```

Assuming your script is a component in your camera's game object.